# Are there any complications to using has_many in relationship with a has_and_belongs_to_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

So imagine a situation where you have many meals. You can then categorize these meals as you see fit. So the two objects would be

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :meal
end

class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :category
end
```

So categories don't really belong to a meal, but meals can belong to many categories.

Is this incorrect? Should category have `has_and_belongs_to_many` instead? Or should this relationship be a `has_many, :through` one?

Comment: you will need a intermediate table to store all the meal and category connections. Checkout more on rails guide how to do that:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

Comment: I know, but will the models be as stated above, or will I need to change one or both of them?

Comment: Both models will need to have a `has_and_belongs_to_many relationship`, since one meal will reference many categories and one category will reference many meals.

Comment: I thought as much. It's just a little confusing, since categories don't really "belong to" a meal.

Comment: I understand, but try to write it on a paper and you will see why it won't work :)